# Is there a way to make the window event to be triggered first

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make the event of the window to be triggered first, on clicking on the #myDiv, is there a way to do it?

```
(function ($, w, d) {
    $(d).ready(function () {
      $(w).click(function() {
         alert('window has been clicked'); 
      });

      $('#myDiv').click(function () {
         alert('myDiv has been clicked'); 
      });
   });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/au1hpj5L/

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the anonymous `#myDiv` function in a `setTimout` call set for 0 seconds, which would delay its execution in the event loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/2y5h8fgz/

```
(function ($, w, d) {
    $(d).ready(function () {
        $(w).click(function() {
           alert('window has been clicked'); 
        });
        $('#myDiv').click(function(){
            setTimeout(function () {
           alert('myDiv has been clicked'); 
        }, 0);
        });
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```